# Colored squares puzzle with Numberjack

Tags: python, constraints, constraint-programming, constraint-satisfaction

I'm going crazy with this problem that I have to solve with Numberjack, that is a library in python for CSP.
We have n x m squares with colored sides. These squares must be arranged in a n x m grid in such a way that the squares' adjacent sides are of the same color. The square can be rotated and shifted. An example:

[image]

I thought about using 4 matrix (one for nord, one for sud, one for west and one for east side ) and a number for a color. Nord(i,j), West(i,j), East(i,j), Sud(i,j) describe the square i,j on the grid. 
Which constraints i have to consider?

Comment: What is a shift? Is that a swap with a neighbor?

Comment: Yes, exactly a swap with a neighbor @Erwin Kalvelagen

Comment: Precisely I have to develop a program where I can only swap the squares and another one where I can swap and rotate too.

Comment: Can you clarify: do you (a) have a heap of coloured tiles that you want to assemble into a colour-matched grid, or (b) already have the tiles arranged in a grid, and you want to compute a series of swap/rotates to transform this into a colour-matched grid?

Comment: Sure! I have an heap of coloured tiles and I want to assemble them into a grid, using numberjack. I have not  to find an algorithm that solve this problem, this is the solver's task (Mistral 2 for example); my guess is to find a representation for the tiles, give the tiles as an input for my model function and find the correct constrains in such a way that my solver can solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As this sounds like homework, let me just outline one model that works:

Describe each given type of tile as a quintuple `(Type,N,E,S,W)`, where
`Type` is an identifier for this type of tile, and `N,E,S,W` are the
colours on the north, east, south and west side.  For each type of tile,
have four such tuples for the different rotations.

Represent the grid with n x m similar tuples `(Type,N,E,S,W)`, where
`Type` ranges over the tile type identifiers, and `N,E,S,W` over the colours.

You then need three types of constraints, all of which should be easily representable in Numberjack (and other finite-domain style solvers):

- every grid tuple matches one of the tile descriptor tuples
- adjacent colours match
- the grid contains the right number of tiles of each type

Comment: How can I create the grid? Like a matrix ? In this case, it is not allowed in numberjack to create matrix with tuples :(

Comment: This is only conceptual. You can use five matrices of integer variables instead, four of which you had already proposed in your question.